# Should a prayer rug look Islamic?

Tags: salat, practical-islam

From my experience, prayer rugs tend to be fairly similar to one another.  I'm not sure if this is considered an important part of prayer, or just a habit that people have gotten in over time.  Here's a random one from the web:

[image: Walters Art Museum [Public domain, CC BY-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) or GFDL (http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html)], via Wikimedia Commons]

*Question*: Should a prayer rug look Islamic?

As I understand, it is not necessary to even use one.  But if one does, does it need to look the part?  Or would anything comfortable and clean (and not un-Islamic) be just as suitable?

I'm thinking of getting a rug so I can pray in the office, but something that doesn't look like a prayer rug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assalamu Alaikum. No it does not have to look a certain way. As long as where you place your hands and head down when in sajood, is a clean pure area, you should be fine. Just make sure that theres no images on it. (Ex. Faces, animals, etc..) I've seen ladies use scarfs on the floor as a prayer mat. I hope this answers your question, and Allah knows best.

Salam.

Answer (score 3):

As Hanuna stated in her answer a prayer rug or carpet or anything you pray on has no predefined look based on shari'a. But the most important is that it doesn't distract you [from praying](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/34), so that you may loose your concentration. This also applies to anything in the room especially in the direction of the Qiblah (I miss a Question on this topic on our site). This is what you should have in mind when making a choice for the rug. I'd recommend simplicity but honestly I often even pray directly on the ground when I know the place is clean.

So for example geometrical drawings or settings would be allowed, but images of living things not.

See also [this](https://islamqa.info/en/161222) salafi fatwa.