# What does "mahram" mean?

Tags: definitions, mahram

I am trying to understand meaning of `mahram`. Can someone explain to me what it means in Islam? I have read about it on the internet but still can't understand its meaning.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to explore and learn more about our site and model by taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: i did, but cant understand the mahram consept

Comment: This is an invitation to learn about the stack exchange model of course you won't find an answer for your question there but an introduction on how this site should work!

Answer (score 2):

Basically a [mahram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahram) is a person who can't marry a woman for ever (it is haram). This means what ever happens he is by default not allowed to marry her according the shari'a.

From a womans perspective her father (and father's father etc.) her sons (and her son's sons etc.) her brothers (no matter if paternal or maternal) her brothers  and sisters sons (and their son's sons etc.) her uncles (maternal and paternal) are mahrams and are quoted in ([24:31](http://legacy.quran.com/24/31)):

> And tell the believing women to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts and not expose their adornment except that which [necessarily] appears thereof and to wrap [a portion of] their headcovers over their chests and not expose their adornment except to their husbands, their **fathers**, their husbands' fathers, their **sons**, their husbands' sons, their **brothers**, their **brothers' sons**, their **sisters' sons**, their women, that which their right hands possess, or those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are not yet aware of the private aspects of women. ...

Read also [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/5538) explaining this.

Comment: so if you are married other people are not allowed see your wife whitout hijab except father, sons brothers sons, uncle

Comment: Yes this is the statement of the fatwa and that interpretation of the verse!

Comment: there is also something about intercourse that i dont understand

Comment: @alino Is it related to this question? Else you should search on the site or ask a new Question.

Comment: as i understand hijab is not enough if you are married. You have to use nakab in front of others?

Comment: @alino on what basis? What is the source of that? this is related http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35874/does-a-muslim-woman-need-to-cover-her-entire-body-including-hands-and-face-dur

Comment: can you please answer this related question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43718/18985

Answer (score -1):

The deep answer is someone who is not likely to be interested in the woman sexually, by direct blood (son,father,uncle, but not cousin), or by other relationships like the father of your husband.

why this is important? because islam makes clear difference between woman relationship with her close family(mehrams) and the outsiders, in the first environment she could wear anything she wants(with logic) , she has completely free life style.
with the outsiders environment(not mahrams) woman should follow some guidelines like wearing hidjab, talk with them in respect way , and not seduce, flirt or being playful. and also avoid staying alone with an outsider in the same room for no important reason.