# Does my grandfather's cousin's daughter have to wear the hijab in the presence of me?

Tags: hijab, mahram, awrah

Is it necessary for my grandfather's cousin's daughter to wear the head-cover in front of me?

Comment: How is your grandfather's cousin's daughter  your aunt?

Comment: No, your aunt would be your fathers sisters. Your fathers cousin, has to wear hijab in present of your father, and your fathers cousins daughter has to wear hijab in front of your father too. If this is true to your father it is also true to you. Generally speaking, yes your fathers cousins daughter has to wear hijab in presence of you and she isn't your aunt.

Comment: Your aunts are your father sisters. How is she your aunt?

Comment: You could marry your cousin in islam. Anyway your grandfathers cousins daughter is far away from an aunt and also far away from a cousin.

Comment: I am not sure, all languages could have their own terms of that, but i guess "relative" is closest in english.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the family tree from you to her, and i'll try to explain it further.

Comment: This is a related post that basically anaswers your issue http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36226/what-does-mahram-mean

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is obligatory for her to observe the Islamic hijab
in your presence since you are not her mahram.

Comment: please add references when answering.  see "[how to answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)"

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The Quran commands women to observe hijab from men, other than mahrams, and your relationship is not listed among the mahrams:

> وقل للمؤمنات يغضضن من أبصارهن ويحفظن فروجهن ولا يبدين زينتهن إلا ما ظهر منها وليضربن بخمرهن على جيوبهن ولا يبدين زينتهن إلا لبعولتهن أو آبائهن أو آباء بعولتهن أو أبنائهن أو أبناء بعولتهن أو إخوانهن أو بني إخوانهن أو بني أخواتهن أو نسائهن أو ما ملكت أيمانهن أو التابعين غير أولي الإربة من الرجال أو الطفل الذين لم يظهروا على عورات النساء ولا يضربن بأرجلهن ليعلم ما يخفين من زينتهن وتوبوا إلى الله جميعا أيه المؤمنون لعلكم تفلحون
>
> And tell the believing women to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts and not expose their adornment except that which [necessarily] appears thereof and to wrap [a portion of] their headcovers over their chests and not expose their adornment except to their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons, their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands possess, or those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are not yet aware of the private aspects of women. And let them not stamp their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment. And turn to Allah in repentance, all of you, O believers, that you might succeed.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 24:31](http://quran.com/24/31)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Should my grandfather's cousin wear hijab in my presence?
Yes, hijab is obligatory on him because he is not a mahram to you.