# Is niqab compulsory in these days for women?

Tags: fiqh, women, sunni, hijab

I know in the early days of Sahaba and Fiqh it was nt compulsory but rather recommended. Now, I saw that there's an established consensus of jurists of Ahle Sunnah wal Jamah that it is compulsory for today.Here is his reference:

> Imam Ibn Raslan, Imam Abdul Bar, Imam Ramali, Imam Badruddin Al Aini,
> Imam Muhammad Ibrahim Al-Wazir etc. have described in their books that
> The ijma/consensus has been established that the women's faces must be covered
> and it is obligatory these days.
>
> [Aun al-Mabud 11/162; Risalatun Fil-Hijabi Was-Sufur 19; Fatawa Ulamail >Baladil Haram 1169; Nihayatul
> Minhaj Ila Sharhil Minhaj: 6/188; Umdadul Kari 20/245; Al Istidkar
> 8/542; The Muslim Woman 202; Kashful Gumati al Adilat al Hijab Fil
> Kitab wal Sunnah, 2nd edition, 161]

Now, what is the actual ruling on this in the Sunni madhabs? Can we go against this consensus? Please answer with references from the early days and also from those who established a consensus of essentiality.

Comment: The topic of niqab was always an opinion-based topic (it could also be socially and/or culturally tinged) it is nothing the majority of scholars ever agreed upon.

Comment: whats the majority's view? and so there was never a consensus? can u write an answer with refs from fiqh please? i need it  really

Comment: As is written your reference needs a reference since it refers to a bunch of books which don't agree to the statement shared. There's an ijma' based for a specific case which is a kind of necessity (the fear of fitna and this can't be totally objective, since humans have different point of views) a general statement was never agreed upon. Since it is also consensus that old women don't need to cover their faces.

Comment: @Medi1Saif you a link from Shamela? I will try to provide. but I haven't found in the provided text about the condition of fitnah stated

Comment: I know that you won't find that, but you won't also find the statement shared above in any of these resources since it looks like a mix of all of them. Note that none of these scholars are known to make correct statements about the consensus. For example, many consider the statements of consensus made by ibn 'Abd al-Barr to be wrong since he does not take into account the opinion of hadith scholars like Imam Ahmad. Nevertheless there's a whole bunch of scholars who would regard Niqab as better and find good arguments to regard it as wajib. But not based on ijma'.

Comment: @Medi1Saif so, in conclusion, even in these day women can reveal face in public, no? can u kindly provide references from fiqh? i really need an answer from Fiqh from Sunni schools and contemporary scholars like Taqi Usmani

Comment: I don't know of any scholar called Taqi Usmani, but the famous salafi scholar and muhaddith al-Albani who was contemporary scholar wrote a book refuting the claims of the hanbali about the prescription of Niqab. At the time of the prophet women were not wearing Niqab by default since the [sahih hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim:645c) says that the women were not recognizable due to the darkness before dawn, if their faces were covered 'Aishah wouldn't have pointed at this fact! Are we better people than the sahabah? Or is niqab an innovation which was not practiced at the time of the prophet?

Comment: @Medi1Saif thank you very much for the convo. it was helpful and also Al-Albani's information. [Mufti Taqi Usmani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taqi_Usmani) is a Pakistani Hanafite [Islamic scholar](https://themuslim500.com/profiles/muhammad-taqi-usmani/) and former judge and very popular.

Comment: Shayekh Nasiruddun Albani(peace on him) gave fatwa and refuted the hanafi madhab that niqab is not mandatory  for women

Answer (score 0):

The issue of whether or not the niqab (face veil) is compulsory for women in Islam is a complex one, with different opinions among scholars and jurists. However, the general consensus among Sunni scholars is that it is mandatory for women to cover their faces in public.

> This consensus is based on various hadiths (sayings) of the Prophet
> Muhammad (peace be upon him) and his companions, as well as the
> interpretation of Quranic verses related to modesty and decency. For
> example, one hadith narrated by Ibn Abbas states, "The Prophet (peace
> be upon him) said: 'A woman is to be covered, except for her face and
> hands.'"

**However, there are some scholars who argue that the niqab is not mandatory, but rather recommended or preferred.** They based their opinion on the interpretation of the same hadiths and Quranic verses, as well as the social and cultural context of the time and place.

> One such scholar is Ibn Hazm, who wrote in his book Al-Muhalla,
> "Covering the face is not obligatory, but rather it is voluntary and
> recommended, based on the level of modesty and piety."

Therefore, while there may be differing opinions among scholars and jurists on this issue, the general consensus among Sunni scholars is that the niqab is mandatory for women in public. It is important to note that the niqab is not a form of oppression against women, but rather a way to protect their modesty and dignity in accordance with Islamic teachings.

Sources:

Sahih Al-Bukhari, Book 60, Hadith 282
Sahih Muslim, Book 32, Hadith 6372
Sunan Ibn Majah, Book 9, Hadith 1918
Al-Muhalla by Ibn Hazm, Volume 3, Page 217

Comment: _However, the general consensus among Sunni scholars is that it is mandatory for women to cover their faces in public._
someone popular here stated it's not correct, there was never an ijma on this. also, mandating the niqab directly contradicts ahadith. one of them is provided by you too, then why write self contradictory answer? @Greenix_3