# What is the ruling with prayer rugs with Islamic pictures?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, sin

I saw a Muslim talk about how prayer rugs with the picture of Makkah (i.e. the Ka’ba) and the Prophet’s Masjid is haram because you’re placing these images on the ground (and some might get distracted upon staring at them, though I’m not too sure how plausible that is).

I myself have also had these doubts on whether it would be halal or haram to use.

They also said that some of them contain faces (not human-like faces) hidden inside.

Is this something to be weary of? Or no?

Comment: Please use meaningful tags: What are halal-certification and source-identification for if the topic is whether something is halal or haram? Further I'd say that your inquiry actually is covered in [Should a prayer rug look Islamic?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34782/should-a-prayer-rug-look-islamic)

Comment: @Medi1Saif I’ve already looked through that article but I couldn’t find the answer I was looking for.